# How to add an object to the chart from the list?

Tags: c++, qt

In the function of the class responsible for displaying the graph, I pass a pointer to a list of objects. Combine the coordinates from the object data into the QAreaSeries and the box in the list QList . I want to display the elements of this list on the chart.

Header:

```cpp
class DevMapViewer : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    DevMapViewer(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

signals:
    void deviceId(QString id);
    void readDataFromFile(void);

protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
    void keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
    void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event);

public slots:
    void deviceSetList(QList<AxDevice *> *data);

private:
    void chartZoom(qreal mZoom);

    uint32_t m_devCount = 0;
    QChart *m_chart;
    QChartView *chartView;
    qreal mFactor=1.0;
    Callout *m_tooltip;
    QList<Callout *> m_callouts;
    QList<QAreaSeries *> *m_series;
    QCategoryAxis *axisX;
    QCategoryAxis *axisY;
    QLineSeries *series0;
    QLineSeries *series1;
    QAreaSeries *series;
};
```

Source:

```cpp
void DevMapViewer::deviceSetList(QList<AxDevice *> *data)
{
    QList<QAreaSeries *> *m_series = new QList<QAreaSeries *>;
    int i = 0;
    while(i<(data->size())){
        QLineSeries *series0 = new QLineSeries();
        QLineSeries *series1 = new QLineSeries();
        QAreaSeries *series = new QAreaSeries();

        series0->append(data->at(i)->getX0(data->at(i)->chanelNum()),
                        data->at(i)->getY0(data->at(i)->chanelNum()));
        series0->append(data->at(i)->getX1(data->at(i)->chanelNum()),
                        data->at(i)->getY0(data->at(i)->chanelNum()));
        series1->append(data->at(i)->getX0(data->at(i)->chanelNum()),
                        data->at(i)->getY1(data->at(i)->chanelNum()));
        series1->append(data->at(i)->getX1(data->at(i)->chanelNum()),
                        data->at(i)->getY1(data->at(i)->chanelNum()));

        series->setLowerSeries(series0);
        series->setUpperSeries(series1);

        m_series->append(series);
        m_series->at(i)->setName(data->at(i)->deviceId());

        m_chart->addSeries(m_series->at(i));
        m_chart->setAxisX(axisX, m_series->at(i));
        m_chart->setAxisY(axisY, m_series->at(i));

        connect(m_series->at(i), 
                &QAreaSeries::hovered, 
                this, 
                &DevMapViewer::tooltip);
        i++;
    }
}
```

When executing a line:

```cpp
m_chart->addSeries(m_series->at(i));
```

program closes with segmentation error from operating system

```
Segmentation fault (signal SIGSEGV)
```

Tried to pass pointers and copies of QList objects.

[Uploaded code to GitHub](https://github.com/Nefistory/mreAXParamMap)

Comment: @eyllanesc Uploaded code to GitHub. So it will be easier to see the idea.

Comment: I have reviewed your code and I have certain doubts, for example, why is it necessary for AxDevice to be a QObject?

Comment: @eyllanesc It may be necessary to expand the functionality in future versions and there will be a need for signals and slots. But now this is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved. Added series to the chart not yet created.
It became:

```
m_chart = new QChart();
emit readDataFromFile();
```

It was:

```
emit readDataFromFile(); m_chart = new QChart();
```